# Is it possible to use Firebase without AngularFire2 in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I want to use `http` requests instead of installing angularfire2

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use the AngularFire2 binding library, you have two options:

- Use the [JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start). The AngularFire2 library is built on top of this SDK, so anything AngularFire can do, you can do on the SDK too.
- Use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start), which requires no SDK whatsoever. The REST API is usable from any platform that can make HTTP calls, which includes any web browser in which Angular 2 will run.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialise your app inside the constructor of the AppComponent:

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);
  }
}
```